# Setting a radio button to be checked as default, only when passing in a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, radio-button

Suppose I have a function like this in React

```
function Stars({handleStarClick, starClicked}) {

    if (starClicked === 3) {
      document.getElementById('star3').checked = true
    }

    return (

    <div className="rate">
        <input onClick={() => handleStarClick(5)} type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5"/>
        <label htmlFor="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
        <input onClick={() => handleStarClick(4)}  type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
        <label htmlFor="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
        <input onClick={() => handleStarClick(3)}  type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
        <label htmlFor="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
        <input onClick={() => handleStarClick(2)}  type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
        <label htmlFor="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
        <input onClick={() => handleStarClick(1)}  type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
        <label htmlFor="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I want the default behavior to have all the radio buttons unchecked. However, let's say in a form a user selects the 3-star radio button, I would like to be able to pass in a prop that allows me to render this component with the 3-star radio button checked. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

In React you shouldn't use `document.getElementById()` to access DOM elements. It should be done using [React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). In this case, you can avoid it.

You can use the following as a prop to make it work:

```
checked={index === starClicked}
```

Your code can be simplified as below:

```js
function Stars({ handleStarClick, starClicked }) {
  return (
    <div className="rate">
      {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => {
        const index = 5 - i;
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <input
              onChange={() => handleStarClick(index)}
              checked={index === starClicked}
              type="radio"
              id={`star${index}`}
              name="rate"
              value={index}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`star${index}`} title="text">
              {index} stars
            </label>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [starClicked, handleStarClick] = React.useState(-1);

  return <Stars handleStarClick={handleStarClick} starClicked={starClicked} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Nice usage of `Array.from` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from